# Django forms: Is it possible to have multiple drop down menus for different tags within a field?

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have a form in a formset where I would like to display multiple drop down menus under a single field 'tests'. I have achieved this in the form of having a single dropdown menu within 'optgroup' tags (see image below).

I guess this way you can only choose a single value.

However, is it possible to 'nest' these drop downs? I.e have them all under one field 'tests',  but be able to have several dropdowns with 'tags' and choose results for each tag? Or do I need a field for each 'tag'?

My forms.py:

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):

    summary = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':3, 'cols':70}),
                label='',
                required=False)

    tests = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())


    class Meta:
        model = ClinicallyReportedSample
        fields = ('id', 'summary', 'tests', 'hilis_reported')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json_data = kwargs.pop('json_data', None)
        super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        crs_obj = self.instance

        for j in json_data:
            if j['lab_no'] == str(crs_obj):
                json = j

        summary = json['summary']
        self.fields['summary'].initial = summary
        self.fields['reported'].label = crs_obj

        tests = json.get('tests', None)
        if tests:

            test_choices = (
                    ('mutated', 'mutated'),
                    ('mutated - see comments', 'mutated - see comments'),
                    ('awaiting confirmation', 'awaiting confirmation'),
                )

            self.fields['tests'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                            required=True,
                            label='Current or repeat samples?',
                            choices=((k, test_choices) for k in tests),
                        )
```

[image]

What I get now:

I would instead want a dropdown for each gene, and those choices. Do I need to make a field for each gene? The problem I have with doing this is that each result can have 0-10 genes, and this would be incredibly difficult to render in a HTML table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to implement something template/client-side to handle that, such as [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) (see the option groups examples).

Then on your form class implement a [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) and/or `clean_[field_name]` method if you need to get your selected data in the format you want.